# how to exclude some users data from query, laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have an query like:

```
$users = DB::table('users')->select('*')->where('status', '=', '1')->get();
```

Now I want to exclude some users from this query which are exists in 2nd table, like the table name is 'users_packages' and the structure is:

```
id     userid     package
1      85         $ 100
2      61         $ 200
3      99         $ 100
4      15         $ 300
```

Now the I want to get all users excluding the users against these user ids :'85, 61, 99, 15'.

How can we achieve this goal? Any special query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could get the user ids from the users_packages table below:

```
$userIds = DB::table('users_packages')->pluck('user_id')->all();
```

After that, you can include this array in your whereNotIn query like this:

```
$users = DB::table('users')->select('*')->where('status', '=', '1')->whereNotIn('id', $userIds)->get();
```